# Should a DAO be used to create a single object?

Tags: java, database, architecture, dao

Should a DAO refer to only one object of the domain? By that I mean if the DAO should be able to assemble only one domain object?

To be more specific, in java I'm implementing a "RoleDAO" to create a "Role" domain object from an Oracle database.

I also have a "Permission" object which as his own PermissionDAO.
So, for methods such as getRolesPermissions, should I put it in the "RoleDAO" or should I create another DAO which isn't related to a specific domain object?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach isn't adding a DAO for relationships, I suggest you to add this method in the owner of the relationship, I mean, if the Role class has a collections of Permissions and you want to find a specific role with the related permissions for me is better adding this method in RoleDAO, but if you don't need the role information and just the permissions information with a specific role id, then add this method in PermissionDAO, greetings.